# How to add external properties into a java class in my maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I wanted to store some properties in a separate config file and then use those properties in my java class. I tried looking at resources and getting things done but its not working. I just started with maven so I am not sure whether I am looking at the right resources or not. I will tell you in simple words what I am want to do - I want to store some values such as path and some other parameters into a seperate config file and I want to use those values in my java class. How to do it in a maven project? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not really about maven but rather java itself.**

First of all, are those properties changed by the user?
If yes, you have to use a location which is outside of the jar. (so the user can actually modify it)
If no, you can use the standard resource location and retrieve data from the jar itself.

Do you want an hybrid approach?
Create a default configuration file inside the resource, then copy it outside while running the program the first time. At runtime, If it exists outside, you will use the one provided by the user otherwise the default one which is inside your jar.

How do you handle a configuration file?
You can do it in several way:

1. **Create a simple class which read() and write() on a plain text file** then
   saves data inside an object
2. **Use a standard notation like json, xml, yaml, csv** etc... web is plenty of libraries to handle those .
3. **Use java serialization** to export the current internal state of your application and load it as you wish but i do not advise it.

What are you really asking for it's how to read and write from a file.
Maven it's a build system to package your application and has nothing to do with your answer.

Comment: Basically I have a maven project , in that I was supposed to make changes to a class. In that I have hardcoded certain parameters which I instead want to take up from a config file so that in future if someone used that code they just need to change the parameters in the config file and the project should work for that without needing any changes in the code. I don't have any prior experience in java I just know the basics that's why I got stuck here , not able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: You can check this [example](https://www.boraji.com/java-bufferedreader-and-bufferedwriter-example) about using two famous classes inside the java.io package
BufferedReader and BufferedWriter, from there you will be able to write and to read from a file

Comment: At this point a simple approach is to use the BufferedWriter to encode properties like this:
`property-name0=value0`
`property-name1=value1`
etc...
So, it will be really easy to write a read function, do you need some code?
I'm pretty sure you should be able to figure it out alone, but i can provide you a class which does that. I'd like to avoid doing your "homework" but more helping you understanding how to be able to do it by yourself.